# Assert and error in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I'm new to Groovy/Grails, I didn't find a good tutorial for the latest grails (3.1.5) so I'm reading a 2.1 book (the definitive guide to grails 2) since the architecture is almost the same.

So the problem is that I can't understand many parts of the codes here's one example :

```
/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage
instructions
 */
@TestFor(Song)
class SongTests {
 void testMinimumDuration() {
 // set the Song class up for constraints testing . . .
 mockForConstraintsTests Song
 // create a new Song
 def song = new Song(title: 'Some Title',
 artist: 'Some Artist',
 duration: 0)
 // make sure that validation fails . . .
 assert !song.validate()
 // make sure that the 'min' constraint failed . . .
 assert 'min' == song.errors['duration']
 }
}
```

and the Song class :

```
class Song {
 String title
 String artist
 Integer duration
}
```

I can't understand many things like what .error('duration') does ?(can't find the "error" method in documentation) and what's 'min' ? there is no "min" constraint in the class declaration !

Comment: I think in 3.xx you use Spock as per the documentation: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/testing.html#unitTestingDomains

Comment: @tim_yates thank you but what about 2.1 ? It is a bad idea to use 2.1 ?

Comment: Why use old things when starting something new?

Comment: because I couldn't find a good tutorial for the new versions :/ 
and the book that I have is really good (comparing to the official tutorial, the only tutorial of 3.1.5) and there is no bigg difference in the architecture of the versions

Comment: Apart from a huge rewrite, and the fact it's now based on Spring Boot and it's now built on Gradle, and it now uses Spock for testing

Comment: Oh ok,  do you have any good tutorial or book that I can follow please ? Is there a bigg community using the latest versions ? (To be sure that I will get help)

Comment: There's here (of course) there's also a slack channel at http://slack-signup.grails.org/ full of people. There's a good tutorial in the docs https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html not sure about books yet

Comment: @tim_yates great! thanks a lot from the slack team ! and I think I will go for the documentation for now